# How can I defer view rendering until some data is loaded from an external source?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My app needs to load some data into the `$rootScope` from an external source when it initializes. Since the data is from an external source, the time required to load the data is not guaranteed. I want to defer the rendering of the view until only after the data is loaded successfully. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note that I am not using the Angular routing for this app.

Here is a [simplified demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qsR6zABnL3TOHeFiJ4bs?p=preview)

Comment: Why aren't you using `$http`? We'll need some more info to answer.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller - I am using $http. It's just in the provided example code I have substituted $http with $timeout, so that I can emulate long delay and thus show the late-binding effect. Please let me know what other info are you looking for. Hit me with your questions. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use `$watch` along with `ng-show` to get the desired result

Comment: @user2104976 - Why do I want to explicitly use `$watch` when `ng-show` is already doing `$watch` in the background?

Comment: @tamakisquare Yeah, you could use only `ng-show` too. But in my applications, I like to initialize the data with some values before fetching it from external source - so `ng-show` will not work for me since the data already contains values just not the ones that I expect. Silly thing actually, one could just use `ng-show` without the need to initialize  - nothing wrong there.

Comment: Let me know if you find an alternative. I have tried `$scope.$apply(fn)` to encapsulate the code.

I also tried to use `$scope.$evalAsync(fn)`, `$timeout(fn, 0)` or some other chained promises.

This article shed some light on the rendering cycles: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: @tamakisquare in that case you are talking, you could consider using `ng-init`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to prevent the view from rendering until an async operation completes without using route resolves, but you could program a custom directive to do the same work.

However, if this is strictly for user experience, then using ngShow would work swimmingly:

```html
<div ng-show="user.name">
  <!-- content won't be visible until data is set -->
</div>
```

Here's an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MXoQNWHvyp9aOXg0QOoC?p=preview

Comment: I would like to update this and say that the ngCloak solves this kind of problem now: See the reference here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

no ngShow needed

Comment: @DanielGroh That might work on initial page load, but I don't think it would work *between* page loads.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it wasn't simply an issue of UI flicker. Because the data wasn't loaded prior to rendering, my bootstrap select wasn't choosing the associated data value. I was able to resolve the problem by placing an "ng-if" in the container wrapping the dropdown select, as below:

```
<div class='bootstrap-select-dropdown-wrapper' ng-if='listofthings.length > 0'>...</div>
```

Hopefully this helps someone that's stuck with a similar problem (note: I've also incorporated the nya-bootstrap-select module into my project - bower install nya-bootstrap-select)